# Laravel Session value is different / not being updated in other Controllers (Redis)

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a controller which sets a session variable upon request from clientside: `session()->put(BrandFilter::class.'.default', $value)`
After setting this, three requests are fired, which should use that variable with `session()->get(BrandFilter::class.'.default')` (I also tried a few seconds delay at that point).

When I refresh my page, it works but when I stay, the variable is the one that it has been before updating it. Also worth mentioning is, that if I do `session()->get(BrandFilter::class.'.default')` right after I set the value in the first controller, the right value is returned.
I also changed the key to something like 'testkey'.
To make sure, that my logic is correct, I replaced the `session()` with a simple `cache()`, which works! (not as a workaround though because the cache key is deleted afterwards. I use redis as cache driver.

Comment: You tried with a key 'testkey' but did it worked or not?

Comment: @dparoli no, didn't work!